# How to calculate the integral $\int x d(4x) $?

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, integration

How can I take the following integral?

$$\int x d(4x) $$

It seems very easy. But it is difficult for me.

Is it equal to $4\times \frac12 \times x^2+c$ ?

Comment: Whatever $d(4x)$ is supposed to mean? Elsewise it probably means $4dx$, in which case the below answer qualifies.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Yes, of course! It's $$4\int xdx=4\cdot\frac{x^2}{2}+C=2x^2+C$$

Comment: Okay thank you.

Comment: You are welcome!

Answer (score 19):

$$\int xd(4x)=\frac14\int (4x)d(4x)=\frac14\frac{(4x)^2}{2}+C=2x^2+C$$